# Keep blank cells visible based on previous cell value (true/false) in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, formula

I am working with a product sheet exported from Shopify with over 1000+ products. I need to create a filter view of *Published* products, however, each product contains variants with only the *parent* cell having a value of True or False.

| Code | Type | Published |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyx-234 | Shirt | True |
| xyx-234 |  |  |
| xyx-234 |  |  |
| xyx-567 | Jumper | False |
| xyx-567 |  |  |
| xyx-567 |  |  |
| xyx-567 |  |  |
| xyx-567 |  |  |
| xyx-567 |  |  |
| xyx-890 | Jeans | True |
| xyx-890 |  |  |
| xyx-890 |  |  |
| xyx-234 |  |  |

Is there a way of keeping empty cells based on the value of the last non-empty cell. Or am I better to try fill the blank cell with the value from above?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
=FILTER(A:C,MMULT(--(A:A=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A:A,C:C=TRUE))),LEN(FILTER(A:A,C:C=TRUE))^0))
```

[image]

**Edit:**

For large amount of data better use `MATCH`:

[image]

```
=FILTER(Products!A:Z,MATCH(Products!A:A,FILTER(Products!A:A,Products!H:H=TRUE),0))
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work – however, is there any way to do it with information that is already being pulled in from another sheet? I'm running some other functions on different columns.

Test sheet can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZZD3DX1MzR6hBCR6n3APvvwqaiamtXqVMWFTOYOwgog/edit#gid=1855691406

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, when I try to apply it to the larger sheet I get an error:

`Error
FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 19043, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.`

Comment: @RobertFarrelly It looks like ```TRANSPOSE``` can't handle that much data. There is another option to use ```MATCH``` instead. See edit.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll give that ago. I really appreciate you taking the time to take a look.